# Item Properties

Tags: c#, xna, items

I'm new to XNA and currently making an RPG-esque game, I want to implement items in an efficient way with fields for name, value etc. How should I go about doing this?

For instance rather than have to do each item over and over and have huge chunks of code for each, how could I make it so I just have to assign the properties specific to each item?

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but it seems you are trying to make your first videogame by jumping into an area that is out of your reach. If this is the case, my advise is to start small (board game, platform game, platform game with a camera, and then an RPG).

Comment: Well it's an RPG-esque game, it has some elements of an RPG but it won't be as massive.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your game components as real world concepts.

For example, think of characters as "having" different components that can be represented in real world concepts.

All of your magic users should have `Magic` (Magic.cs)

All of your living creatures should have `Vitals` (Vitals.cs)

All of your humanoids should have an `Inventory` (Inventory.cs)

All of your weapon wielders should have a `Hand` (Hand.cs) that may or may not have a `Weapon` in it (weapon.cs).

Comment: So what if I wanted an item that has a string for name, int for attack damage etc, but I want these to be 'fields' rather than separate variables for each different item?

So I have like
Item <itemname>
then I can say like
<itemname>.Name = "name"
<itemname>.Damage = 13
etc.

Comment: Fields are quite desirable.  However, I don't find it likely that you would change the damage for all 'axes' in the game at the same time.  It might be best to have default values based on the name or type of a weapon to determine the damage when the weapon is instantiated.  All weapons could be cloned based on a set of parent weapons that never change.  Then, through the course of the game, individual weapons could be tweaked if desired.  (i.e. losing damage over time due to rust, not being sharpened, etc.)  The original (parent) objects would never change.

Comment: Ah I see, so would each weapon type be it's own .cs or could I put them all under 1 .cs?

Comment: All weapons could easily be 1 .cs file.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I know I should probably read up on C# more in-depth but I have to complete a major in the next few months and I had to just dive straight in!
So would the Weapons.cs file have a method for each type? Could you possible elaborate on this a little, sorry. :\

Comment: You would have an abstract Weapon base class. Then you inherit that, and possibly make an Axe class. And this is the class you'd actually be instantiating. Weapon might have properties like Damage, Durability and Attack Speed. One or more of these properties may be overwritten in Axe, to set a different default value for Attack Speed or so. Hopefully you get where I'm going with this. Have a base skeleton for all weapons, and "fill out" the content in the inheriting classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a full RPG sample on the XNA site here that has much of what you describe http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/roleplaying_game